# Looking for dynamic kernel parameters from sysctl -a command

Tags: linux, kernel-parameters

as title states, I'm looking to select both dynamic and fixed variables from sysctl -a command. Some parameters get changed every reboot? and I would like to have list of both dynamic and fixed.

As I don't have much experience, only thing I have tried is to create the file with parameters that differed after reboot (so I made one list before and after reboot) and compared it. I did this multiple times, but the amount of variables was always different.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just populate sysctl.conf with desired parameters?

Comment: This thing should be part of the healthcheck script on servers. I want it to log the parameters into the file, but only of those wich are dynamic. I dont need to change the values.